# JavaScript : Add time loading function for form

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Im working on a native JavaScript/Ajax based sign-up form. The form uses an ajax function to send the data to a PHP engine which queries the database and what-not.

I'm wondering how to add loading function using JavaScript that allows me to show a loading animation while the PHP is being queried.

Ideally, I'd like to setup some sort of `if` statement checks how long the query takes and will only return the result after at least a minimum amount of time (like 3 seconds). Otherwise the loading animation will just flash on/off because the data-base query is too quick.

The JS looks like this:

```
function xmlhttpPost(strURL) {
        var xmlHttpReq = false;
        var self = this;
        // Mozilla/Safari
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        // IE
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
        self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
            updatepage(self.xmlHttpReq.responseText);
        }
        }
        self.xmlHttpReq.send(getquerystring());
    }

// send form data
function getquerystring() {
   var form = document.getElementById('register-form');
   var firstname    = document.getElementById('firstname').value;

   qstr = 'firstname=' + escape(firstname);
   return qstr;
}

// return form data
function updatepage(str){
var result = document.getElementById("result");
result.innerHTML = str;
}
```

So what I want to do, is while `updatepage(str)` runs, the loading animation (which can just be gif) is run for a minimum of 3 seconds, then the result is displayed.

What I have at the moment is this:

```
function updatepage(str){

var result = document.getElementById("result");
   // display gif;
setTimeout(function(){
   // remove GIF
  result.innerHTML = str;
},3000);
}
```

The issue I see with how I have it setup at the moment is that if DB query takes 5 seconds, the result will actually be displayed in 8 seconds.

Is this the best way of handling this? Or is there a more elegant solution? What's the standard way of doing this kind of thing?

Comment: You need to show the code where you make the actual ajax request: There you can manipulate the html when the function is called and do that again when the results come back.

Comment: Javascript won't really know anything about what's going on in the server-side code.Think of client-side and server-side as two guys yelling at each other in two room while they're both working.  JS dude yells at PHP dude and says "I need some data rendered in a template!" crosses his arms and starts tapping his toe.PHP dude gets to work and builds that (query DB, assemble template) then sends it back "JS dude I have that for you it's..." and then yells each character of the html one at a time.  JS dude, once received, stops tapping his toe none the wiser about what php really did.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that all in your `xmlhttpPost()` function:

- Set a variable with the current time at the start;
- Add / show your image;
- In the `onreadystatechange` compare the current time with the time set at the start, if the difference is 3 seconds or more, remove the image. Otherwise set a timeout for the remaining time and remove the image then.

Comment: Could you post a snippet example though. I'm wonder how to carry the variable from the xmlhttpPost() function to the onreadystatechange.

Comment: @user3143218 Just declare it at the start of `xmlhttpPost()` with `var currentTime = new Date().getTime();` and it will be available in the `onreadystatechange` function as well. Not in your other functions and main code of course...

Comment: It doesn't carry over, they're declared in two different functions. How about if I wrap them in a document.ready ? Would that carry the variable?

Comment: @user3143218 That's weird, I guess in that case you'd have to use `self.currentTime` like you do with `xmlHttpReq`.